# inserting every row in grideview

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert every row in the GridView into a table on a click of button. My problem with the code below is that the data was inserted but i cant handle the exception i used this code

```
string constring = @"Data Source=WINCTRL-RDJN6O6;Initial Catalog=Care_AlexDemo;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TeseI VALUES(@Emp_name, @Emp_number)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_name", row.Cells["Emp_name"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_number", row.Cells["Emp_number"].Value);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
```

Comment: What Exception you receive? Have you tried searching for it on the web? Try enclosing your code in `try...catch`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the variable 'row', I suppose it means every row in the DataGridView.Rows, so you try to insert rows to the database one by one? Generally I'd like to insert all rows once with 'INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] SELECT ...' statement. so the code may be like this:

```
StringBuilder strsql = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO TeseI ");
foreach (var row in DataGridView.Rows)
{
    strsql.AppendFormat(" SELECT '{0}', '{1}' UNION ALL ", row.Cells["Emp_name"].Value, row.Cells["Emp_number"].Value);
}
// remove the last 'UNION ALL '
strsql.Remove(strsql.Length - 10, 10);
string constring = @"Data Source=WINCTRL-RDJN6O6;Initial Catalog=Care_AlexDemo;Integrated Security=True";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql.ToString(), con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
```

by the way, I think we can remove the explicit invoke of 'con.Open()' and 'con.Close()' methods, since we use the 'using' statement

I just give the way I do cause you didn't show the exception message. Anyway,
Hope this can help